# Replacing with Javascript Conditional

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using this javascript to replace all of my links with registration messages:

```
<script>
function replaceLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('.restore a:link');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].innerHTML = 'DOWNLOAD register here.';
        links[i].href = 'register.php';
    }
}
</script>
```

**The problem:**

It's replacing all thumbnail images (that link to their full-size images), too. I can't apply a specific CSS selector to just links because I'm using vBulletin and it would apply it to both links and images inside of the post content.

**Does anyone know how I can...**

forbid this Javascript from applying to links that end with .jpg, .gif, etc -- so it only rewrites the links, and not the thumbnails that link to their full sized images?

Comment: If it helps any, this is what the images use for their link/css

`<a id="attachment234234234" rel="Lightbox_5234234" href="http://www.domain.com/attachments/filename123123123.png">

<img class="thumbnail" border="0" pagespeed_url_hash="2832013083" style="float:CONFIG" alt="Blah blah blah" src="http://www.domain.com/attachments/filename123123123.png" title="blah blah blah"></img>`

Comment: @AmitJoki https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link

Comment: check out my answer too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check link href with simle regexp and proceed only if test is false:

```
function replaceLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('.restore a:link');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (/\.(png|jpe?g)$/.test(links[i].href)) continue;
        links[i].innerHTML = 'DOWNLOAD register here.';
        links[i].href = 'register.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: I am seriously, madly in love with you right now. THANK YOU! Yes, it worked perfectly. You are a genius.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line `var links = document.querySelectorAll('.restore a:link');` to:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.restore a:link:not([href$=".jpg"]):not([href$=".jpeg"]):not([href$=".png"])');
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just too easy to avoid (just seeing the code, or deactivating javascript), I suggest (if you can) install a plugin or make it you (maybe just a patch).

In fact, I think you can disable anonymous download permission in the [built-in settings](https://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/main/attachment_settings), without installing anything.
But if you wanna do it with a JavaScript, at least add some style (then deactivating JavaScript will not show the link):

[Try this code, first without JavaScript, then run replaceLinks()](http://jsfiddle.net/U4Dyq/)

```
<style>
.restore a:link:not([href$=".jpg"]):not([href$=".jpeg"]):not([href$=".png"]){display:none}
</style>
<script>
function replaceLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('.restore a:link:not([href$=".jpg"]):not([href$=".jpeg"]):not([href$=".png"])');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        console.log(i,links[i]);
        links[i].innerHTML = 'DOWNLOAD register here.';
        links[i].href = 'register.php';
        links[i].style.display='inherit';
    }
}
</script>
```